# Compare Mysql Field Value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named 'jobs' with field 'categories'.

Now Values in my category field is like this

```
368,369,372,379,380,381 
368,369,372
369,373,374,375,376
491,492
```

& i am getting values with search like this

```
'368','374','490'
```

Now how to compare myvalue to field value, I can't use "IN" in this stage.
In above case,

If i have values like "'368','374','490'" this, i want first three rows, beacause it contains atleast one value from my list.

how can i do this? Please suggest.

Comment: First of all, you should not store data like this in general, but _normalize_ your data structure instead. But you can make this work by using FIND_IN_SET multiple times (one call for each of your search values).

Answer (score 0):

if you happy to use in programming end (i.e. using php) , you can pull those database data into an associative array. Then you can easily that array for your data manipulation. In php there are many inbuilt functions for arrays. you can use those.

[http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php)

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php